# Naive question about probability

Tags: probability

Let $S = [0,1] \times [0,1]$. Let $A = (\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1])\times (\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1])$. Well, we know that the Lebesgue measure of $A$ is zero. Does this means that if i throw some darts to a target S, i'll never reach rational points ?

I'm sorry about this silly question, but I'm just curious about the meaning of an event having probabily zero.

Comment: Can you measure the position of the tip of the dart accurately enough to tell whether it landed on a rational point or not?

Comment: Let's assume that i can .

Comment: Probability zero does not mean impossible. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely

Comment: In that case, yeah, it may happen, but with probability zero :-)

Comment: I think there is some information missing from the question here. What if the probability of hitting $0$ is exactly $1$? Really depends on your probability measure.

Comment: @par It's perfectly standard practice to assume a uniform distribution, if one isn't explicitly given.

Comment: If you throw your hypothetical hyper-physical dart and exactly hit $(x_0,y_0)$ (no matter if the coordinates are rational or - more liekly - transcendental, noncomputable, nondescribable), then you will argue that the probability of exactly hitting the one-point set $\{(x_0,y_0)\}$ is $0$ and also was $0$ before your throw. So, as has been pointed out, probability zero is not th esame as impossible. Then again, one has to question whether probaility measures describe your theoretical dart at all.

Comment: Naive question to the OP: have you ever seen darts located at a **point** of the target? Each time I looked, the location of the dart was a vaguely delimited region with positive measure.